# SQL SUM top 5 values then JOIN results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

I want to return the top 5 most voted items, sorted by vote count.
I suppose the best way to do it would be to sum each row's `votes_up` and `votes_down`, then take the top 5 of those and join it with the other table.

Here are my existing tables, Items.ID maps to the Votes.item_ID:

```
Items
+----+--------+---------+
| ID |  name  | site_ID |
+----+--------+---------+
| 10 | box    |     111 |
| 11 | hammer |     222 |
| 12 | drill  |     333 |
| 13 | nail   |     444 |
+----+--------+---------+

Votes
+----+---------+----------+------------+
| ID | item_ID | votes_up | votes_down |
+----+---------+----------+------------+
|  1 |      10 |       25 |         20 |
|  2 |      11 |      200 |        100 |
|  3 |      12 |      100 |         50 |
|  4 |      13 |       50 |         20 |
+----+---------+----------+------------+
```

These are the results I would like to get back:

```
+--------+-------+
|  name  | votes |
+--------+-------+
| hammer |   100 |
| drill  |    50 |
| nail   |    30 |
| box    |     5 |
+--------+-------+
```

Comment: What did you tried to do? Where was a problem?

Comment: See this Wikipedia page showing the row-count restriction SQL syntax for various databases:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#Result_limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   Items.name, votes_up-votes_down AS votes_num
FROM     Items, Votes
WHERE    Items.id = Votes.item_id
ORDER BY votes_num DESC
LIMIT    5;
```

Databases first do `JOIN` then `LIMIT`, otherwise it is likely to lose tuples. You can verify this using `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` statements if you're using MySQL or PostgreSQL. If you want to do top 5 first, you have to do it manually:

```
SELECT I.name, V.votes_num AS votes_num
FROM   Items I, 
  (SELECT item_ID, votes_up-votes_down AS votes_num
   FROM   Votes ORDER BY votes_num DESC LIMIT 5) V
WHERE  I.ID = V.item_ID
ORDER BY votes_num DESC;
```

Checkout this [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdc58/1); it returns the results you want.

```
NAME    VOTES_NUM
hammer  100
drill   50
nail    30
box     5
```

Comment: Thanks, how about the limit 5 part?

Comment: @RyanKoehler If you're using MySql or postgresql, you can use LIMIT 5. See my updated post.

Comment: Does this way join all the rows first then limit, or find the top 5 then join?

Comment: @RyanKoehler SQL does not do limit first by default since it's likely to lose tuples. You can use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to view the query plan generated by your system (if you're using MySQL or PostgreSQL).

Comment: thanks, I needed to add another `ORDER BY votes_num DESC` to the last line on your second example.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT i.name AS name, v.votes_up-v.votes_down AS votes
FROM items AS i
JOIN votes AS v ON v.item_id=i.id
ORDER BY votes DESC
LIMIT 5 ;
```

I think `SELECT TOP 5` is MS SQL syntax.

Comment: you can use the alias in the `order by` clause, example `ORDER BY votes DESC`

Comment: I didn't realise you could do that. It will make _ad hoc_ queries much easier. Thanks.